# Счетчик на JS с возможностью вводить новые данные при активном подсчете

Tags: javascript, html

1. есть ценник товара
2. есть 3 дополнительные примочки, которые можно заказать вместе с товаром (при активации чекбокса(1 чекбокс - 1 примочка)). Каждая примочка имеет свою цену.

Написал код, который при активации чекбокса, суммирует цену товара и примочки и выводит ее на страницу с анимацией счетчика.

Проблема в том, что если последовательно активировать три чекбокса, не дождавшись пока закончится анимация предыдущего суммирования, то общая сумма выходит не правильной. Одна сумма накладывается на другую, а не просчитывается последовательно.

Например: товар - 550р, примочка 1 - 80р, примочка 2 - 120р, примочка 3 - 100р.
В сумме выходит 850. Но если быстро нажать все три чекбокса, то сумма выйдет меньше.

Задача такая - при какой бы скорости не нажимались чекбоксы, на страницу должна выходиться правильная сумма с анимацией счетчика. Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
codepen.io/Ilgiz51/pen/OJZeZqB?editors=1010
```

Comment: сбрасывать интервал для уже выполняющейся функции прокрутки счетчика при изменении чекбоксов и начинать прокрутку заново?